# Is this question proper? "Solve $\log_{10}x\in\mathbb{R}$."

Tags: notation

> Is this question proper? "Solve $\log_{10}x\in\mathbb{R}$."?

I know that $\log_{10}x\in\mathbb{R}$ means $x\in(0,\infty)$, but can we write "Solve $\log_{10}x\in\mathbb{R}$." as a question alone? Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to solve? What would the correct answer be?

Comment: Rather than "solve", maybe you could write "Find all x such that $\log _{10}x \in R$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it would be better to ask, "For what $x$ is $\log_{10} x \in \mathbb{R}$?" When you say "solve" it suggests there are a finite number of solutions, and there aren't finitely many.

Comment: But "Solve $x+1>0$", which has finitely many solutions, is a proper question...

Comment: Hm, first, do you mean "infinitely" many? This is fairly subjective, I suppose, but I wouldn't use the phrase "Solve." What resonates better for me is: "For what $x$ is $x+1 >  0$?" 


Alternately if you go with what BobaFret says, "Solve $x+1>0$." makes sense because you are simplifying the inequality and isolating $x$ to one side, thereby getting information about $x$ itself.

Comment: Yes, I mean "infinitely".

Answer (score 0):

"Solve $\log_{10}x$" may make sense if you interpret "solve" as evaluate/simplify. For example: "Solve $\log_{10}100$":

$\log_{10}100=\log_{10}10^2=2$